# HTML/CSS/Boostrap5 Website Nav Bar & Positioning Issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am troubling in **navbar positioning.**

1. My **navbar items** are disappeared after creating the image below. I have tried to adjust the **position of elements** but still doesn't work:((
2. I m also trying to making a **fixed-top navbar**, it doesn't work too:((

I am bad in positioning, hope someone can show me how to solve the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

      <title>Nav</title>

       <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <style>
        
        .carousel-item{
            height:32rem;
            background:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300);
            color:white;
            position:relative;
            top:0;
        }

        .container{
            position:absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right:0;
            padding-bottom: 50px;
        }

        nav{ 
            min-height: 6vh;
            background-color: black;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 100%;

        }

        nav .navbar-nav{
          position:relative;
        }

        nav .navtoggler .navbar-toggler-icon{
          background-color: white;
          color:lightgray;
          margin-left: 0px;
        }

        nav .logo{
          font-size: 2em;
          text-decoration: none;
          color:white;
          font-weight:bolder;
          font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }

        nav .collapse a{
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: medium;
          color:lightgrey;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          text-decoration: none;
          text-align: center;
          word-spacing: 1px;
        }

        nav .collapse a:hover{
            color:hotpink;
        }

        nav .navbar-nav ul{
          list-style: none;
        }

        nav .nav-link{
            display:flex;
            width:30%;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            word-spacing: 10px;
        }

        nav .btn{
          border:1px solid hotpink;
          color:white;
        }

        nav .btn:hover{
          color:hotpink;
        }

        .main{
          margin-top: 30px;
        }

      </style>
      
  </head>

  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-lightdark my-3">
        <div class="container ">
          <a class="logo " href="index.html" aria-current="page">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:50px; height:55px;"class="d-inline-block mt-2">Fit Fit Fitness
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-light bg-light" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggler" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
            <!--Related links to other aspects of the website(only for design purpose, not part of the project) -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#fp-section2-thelatest">TheLatest</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#fp-section3-workout">Workout</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Food&Nutrition</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Athlete&Celebrities</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Apparel&Gear</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
              <button class="btn btn-small" type="submit">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

        <main role="main">
      
         <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="container">
              <span class="carousel-artCategory">Food & Nutrition › Weight Loss</span>
              <h1 class="carousel-artTitle">Four Easy Change Ups You Can Do Today To Burn More Fat</h1>
                <p>
                  <span class="carousel-artCite">By Train 
                    <time datetime="2017-02-14"> 14 Jul, 2022</time>
                  </span>
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Read</a>
              <a></a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </main>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to insert keyword " fixed-top" into the class of nav, but it doesn't working:((
Besides,

Answer (score 1):

When using `position:absolute;` the element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, meaning changing it to `position:sticky;` or removing the line entirely in the `container` class should fix your issue.

Comment: could you mark my answer as the correct one?